# What is super pointing to in the following code?

Tags: java, variables, reference, super

*What address is super in 4th line pointing to in the following code?*

```
public class SuperChk {
    private void test() {
        System.out.println(toString());
        System.out.println(super.toString()); //4
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperChk sc1 = new SuperChk();
        sc1.test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it this way.

Implicitely, your class will inherit from the superclass Object so you can access your object either with an `Object` reference or with a `SuperChk` reference

**Object**

```
public class Object {
    // Other methods

    public String toString(){
        // This is the method super.toString() will use once called in SuperChk
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }

}
```

**SuperChk**

```
public class SuperChk extends Object {
    private void test() {
        System.out.println(toString());
        System.out.println(super.toString()); //4
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperChk sc1 = new SuperChk();
        sc1.test();
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
Hello world
SuperChk@15db9742
```

You can see that the `toString()` method from the Object class prints :

- The class name first.
- Then "@"
- Then the hexadecimal representation of the `HashCode` which is also defined in a method of the superclass `Object`

Comment: Is the getClass() calling the class in which toString() method is inherited?

Comment: @Alvin3001 getClass() will get you the class name of the object from the Heap. Even if your reference is from a parent class.

Comment: So, here hashcode() is also getting the integer value of the the address pointed by sc1?

Comment: @Alvin3001 Yes, it is the hashcode of your SuperChk object exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in Java all derive from `Object`. Since you have no explicit parent class, then the parent is `Object` and `super` is referencing `Object`. [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)  does support the [`toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). See the [Java class hierarchy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

[image]

Comment: But why is it referencing the same address as referenced by sc1?

Comment: @Alvin3001 I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you saying `System.out.println(super.toString())` is printing "Hello World"? That wasn't clear from your original question.

Comment: @Alvin3001 Even if toString() is overridden, calling super. before the method makes sur you're referencing to how the method is written in the direct parent class.

Comment: @lurker No, what I meant is if I include System.out.println(sc1); in main method, it gives the same address value as given by System.out.println(super.toString()); in test(). So why is sc1 and super pointing to the same object?

Comment: Because they are the same object?

Comment: @Alvin3001 because even though it is the same object, you can access it with either an Object reference or a SuperChk reference

Comment: @Ben Knoble So, does that mean here super is referring to the upcasted sc1?

Comment: Sort of. It points back to the methods contained in the superclass. Which is class Object

Answer (score 0):

`super` is not an expression. So `super` does not "point to" anything, and you cannot use `super` by itself.

`super.something()` is an expression that allows you to call a method on the object that `this` points to, but the lookup for which implementation to call proceeds up from the superclass of the class whose code this is in, rather than up from the object's runtime class as would happen if you did `this.something()`.

Here, both `toString()` and `super.toString()` are called on the object that `this` points to (which is a `SuperChk` instance). However, they call different `toString()` implementations -- in the first case, the lookup is based on the runtime class of the object, which is `SuperChk`, and `SuperChk` does provide its own implementation of `toString()`, so `SuperChk`'s implementation is used. In the second case, the lookup is based on the class that is the superclass of the class the code is in (`SuperChk`), which is `Object`, so `Object`'s `toString()` is used.